# Defining a function as a set, and proper use of set notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us define a set $R=\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R}\mbox{, }b=\sqrt{a-2}\}$. Is the set $R$
  well defined? What if we consider the situation where $a=-1$ in which case it $a\in\mathbb{R}$, but it $\sqrt{-1}=b\notin\mathbb{R}$ 
 we might consider that we are left with the ordered pair $(-1,\mbox{ })\in R$ (i'm not sure if this really constitutes an ordered pair or not). Or, is there an implied 'and' condition that all three properties must be true, so that we do not consider the situation when $a=-1$.

I only ask this question because I thought that in order for a relation to be a function it must assign *every* element of the domain to an element in the codomain. If $(-1,\mbox{ })\in R$
  then $R$
  is not a function, however if $(-1,\mbox{ })\notin R$
  then $R$
  would be a function. Is this correct? Also wouldn't it be better to define $R=\{(a,b) : a\in [2,\infty), b\in\mathbb{R_+}, b=\sqrt{a-2}\}$, or is this unnecessarily cumbersome?

Comment: @GitGud Actually, a bit confused by the set $\{ x\in\mathbb{R} : \frac{1}x\neq 0\}=\mathbb{R}$ Since, $\frac{1}x$ never equal zero? but when we consider $x=0$ then $\frac{1}x$ is undefined so I am confused on if  $0$  belong to the set.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment before you wrote yours. I didn't say $\{x\in \Bbb R\colon \dfrac 1x\neq 0\}=\Bbb R$. As you correctly noted, $0$ isn't the LHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implied *and*: your set $R$ consists precisely of the ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ such that $a\in\Bbb R$ **and** $b\in\Bbb R$ **and** $b=\sqrt{a-2}\}$. Its domain is therefore $[2,\to)$, the set of real numbers greater than or equal to $2$. There’s no real need to pin down the domain and codomain in the description of the set of ordered pairs: it makes the description harder to read, and the information can more easily be given separately. That is, one can define $R$ as you did and then specify whether it’s to be considered as a function from $[2,\to)$ to $\Bbb R$, a function from $[2,\to)$ to the non-negative reals, a partial function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, or what.

Comment: Thanks! But, I have another question related to this. When we are drawing a circle diagram to represent a function, if we don't map one element from the domain (or the circle from which the arrows are exiting) into the the codomain then there is no function right? Because a function must know what to do with every element it encounters, right?

Comment: @JimmyJackson: There is a function whose domain is not the entire set represented by the circle; such functions are sometimes called *partial functions* on that entire set.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: @JimmyJackson: You’re welcome!